# Qt уменьшение "веса" проекта

Tags: qt, c++

Программирую на Qt (начал недавно решил поучаствовать в конкурсе но в нем есть ограничение по весу игры 5 мб)
Проект вида "Hello world"(не консольный) после компиляции весит со всеми библиотеками больше 10 мб

Искал в Google большинство воды самый развернутый ответ [здесь](http://www.prog.org.ru/topic_3974_0.html), но я к сожалению не смог разобраться в этом + сейчас у меня Qt 4.7.х а там для 4.2.х. Кто нибудь может объяснить как уменьшить вес исполняемых фалов и dll.

Ещё вопрос, мигрировал с Builder c++ (нет работы) в VS с++ (как понял MFC и WinApi уже не торт а представленный с++/CLR убог) остановился на Qt (вроде все устраивало но вот такие косяки) может на что то я еще не обратил внимание? (желателен RAD подход)

Comment: WinApi ещё какой торт, если уметь правильно готовить и применять.

Если пишете игру, то Вам скорее всего нужен какой нибудь openGL/DirectX движок, а не qt.

Comment: Буду кэпом. Вы exe файл паковали? Статическая или динамическая линковка?

Comment: пробовал. статически не  смог но люди сумевшие это сделать смогли сэкономить 300 кб это меня не спасет 

делаю платформер прикрутить openGl вроде могу

Comment: @Дима Partizan тогда и используете какую-нибудь кроссплатформенную прослойку на OpenGL. Я что-то увидел QT, но не увидел, что эта игра :)

А вообще, не может QT файл после упаковки весить так много...

Comment: Какой у тебя режим сборки? Если "Отладка", то поменяй на "Релиз", должно помочь уменьшить вес программы.

Comment: Попробуйте пересобрать Qt без модулей, которые вам не нужны, стилей, т.е. выкидывайте всё что можно и не нужно. Попробуйте запаковать все либы, сам бинарник (пакеров много, экспериментируйте). Попробуйте поиграться с параметрами компилятора.

Comment: пробовал я релиз. проблема очень распространена но толкового решения нету

Comment: @Дима Partizan, повторюсь QT -- не лучшее решния для создание __чисто__ игр

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй сжать упаковщиком исполняемых файлов, например UPX'ом. Обычно он сжимает больше, чем в 2 раза, как раз с небольшим запасом получатся твои 5 МБ.